# A simple label for an entire MapServer mapfile?

Tags: labeling, mapserver, legend, mapfile

I want to incorporate a simple text label into a mapfile-based map, such that the file's resulting images always display a specific text string (ideally in white over a black background) along the top of the image.

The image's pixel dimensions are known, but the map's extent will depend on outside factors; I'd rather not orient the label to spatial coordinates, but if I have to I will.

Despite how simple this seems to me, I can't seem to find any way to do it, including with legends (which don't seem to be super-imposed on the map anyway, but somehow work differently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a point layer with a fixed feature and label and set it as a default layer. A sample mapfile follows. I wrote some comments for helping you to find the place to make edits for fine tuning.

```
LAYER
  NAME "copyright"
  METADATA
    "wms_title"     "copyright"
  END
  STATUS DEFAULT
  TYPE POINT
  TRANSFORM ll #set the image origin to be lower left
  FEATURE
    POINTS
      108 -8 #set the offset from lower left position in pixels
    END
    TEXT " © 2017 Our Company" #this is your displaying text
  END
  CLASS
    LABEL #defines the font, colors etc. of the text
      FONT "arial"
      TYPE TRUETYPE
      SIZE 15
      BUFFER 1
      COLOR 255 255 255 #white text
      STYLE #defines the box behing the label
         GEOMTRANSFORM LABELPOLY
         COLOR 0 0 0 #black box
         OUTLINECOLOR 255 0 0 #red border
      END #style
      FORCE TRUE
    END #label
  END #class
  UNITS PIXELS #sets the units for the feature object
END #layer
```

Because layer has status DEFAULT it will be rendered always and the result will look like this

[image]